# Yii2 url rules using slug for multiple controllers eg domain.com/slug

Tags: yii2, url-routing

I'd like to set the url rules for someting like: www.domain.com/slug in url for multiple controllers. I have one model "Content" and there is a column called content type in the "Content" model. Eg. content_type = 1 means contest, content_type = 2 means post, content_type = 3 means product etc. I have created a controller for each of the content_type, contestController, postController, productController.

I wonder if there is a way to keep the urls in the following format for few different controllers:

```
'<slug:.*?>'=>'contest/view', // content type contest - contestController
'<slug:.*?>'=>'post/view', // content type post - postController
'<slug:.*?>'=>'product/view', // content type product - productController
```

it does work with just one rule above as per yii documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not direct answer but, have you considered another approach?

1. Send everything to 1 controller

   `'<slug:.*?>'=>'post/view',`

   - on frontend part user will not know which controller is actually used, but you can detect type after you find model by slug.
2. Split router by controller

   `'post/<slug:.*?>'=>'post/view',`

   - you should know, when placing link to that page, which type is used
3. Split router by type flag (not tested)

   `'<slug:[\w][\-\w]*?>/post'=>'post/view',`

   `'<slug:[\w][\-\w]*?>/product'=>'product/view',`

Other then that I do not see how it could work.

Comment: thanks @Ripper, i did try both approaches and they are working well, I was hoping there is any other way to resolve it using just slugs